# Is there a way to be explicit on .select() columns when using .includes() in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to optimize my query for RAM usage and a table that is in the .includes(:ocr) has too many columns on it (and also a large-sized column).  Is there a way that I can still utilize Rails' .includes() but pick out explicit .select() columns from the includes() tables?

I want to exclude using an N+1 which is what a .joins() generates.

ie.

```
User.select(:email).includes(:ocr => select(:small_value_only))
```

Comment: What is the current RAM usage by selecting all columns?

Comment: 350MB, the column i'm trying to remove is a text column that is sometimes 2-3MB large.

Comment: You could batch the records using one of the batch AR methods.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498412/712765) generates a single SQL query that returns only the `email` and `small_value_only` columns. What don't you like about it. By the way, `joins` explicitly _avoids_ [the N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97308/712765). You probably mean something else.

Comment: Hey @OldPro, I'm not only trying to get single fields, I have a handful of fields that I need, thus pluck won't work.

Comment: You can pluck as many fields as you want, just list them in `pluck`. The example in your question only gets 2 fields. Please provide a better example if you want a different answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't give much information on how your tables are set, so I'll assume that User `belongs_to :ocr`, User has an `ocr_id` column, and the ocr table's name is `ocr`.

You should use `joins` instead of `includes`, that's how you generate an INNER JOIN query and be able to retrieve the joined table's column(s). Finally you can alias the column name with `AS`, so it's easier to retrieve in your model:

```
users = User.joins(:ocr).select(:email, :ocr_id, '`ocr`.`small_value_only` AS `ocr_sma`')

users.each do |user|
  user.email # Users.email for this record
  user.ocr_sma # Joined Ocr.small_value_only for this record
end
```

(Obviously I aliased it `ocr_sma`, but you can give it the name you want)

Comment: Thanks @Benj. The joins works but it still generates an N+1 query.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really only trying to get columns of data rather than full ActiveRecord objects, you should use `pluck` instead of `select`. Speeding up these kinds of big queries is exactly what `pluck` was created for. Instead of all of the overhead that goes with creating all the ActiveRecord objects for all your data, `pluck` just returns an array of data:

```
values = User.includes(:ocr).pluck(:email, "ocr.small_value_only")
# SELECT "user"."email", ocr.small_value_only FROM "users"
#   LEFT OUTER JOIN "ocrs" ON "ocr"."user_id" = "users"."id"
#
# [["email_1", 3], ["email_2", 7]] # 3 and 7 are the small values
```

If you want ActiveRecord objects but want to skip filling in some of the data, then it is the same as above but replace `includes` with `left_joins` and `pluck` with `select`

```
values = User.left_joins(:ocr).select(:email, "ocr.small_value_only")
# SELECT "user"."email", ocr.small_value_only FROM "users"
#   LEFT OUTER JOIN "ocrs" ON "ocr"."user_id" = "users"."id"
#
# #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<user id: 1>, #<user id: 2>]>
```

Either way, as you can see, the `SELECT` statement is the same and only the selected columns of data are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to say that the following options are necessarily better than what [Benj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491435/3206935) and [Old Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498412/3206935) suggest, but rather want to provide some more alternatives.

The first one makes use of the `includes` method as that is what OP asked for. But as `includes` will by default select all columns of the primary model (`User`), one first has to remove that default selection via the [except](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-except) method:

```
User.includes(:ocr).except(:select).select(:id, 'ocr.small_value_only')
```

Of course, using `join` in the first place would be easier.

The following options stem from my dislike for having strings in AR queries as it tends to rely on knowledge about the called model which AR should actually abstract for you, i.e. the name of the database table (`ocr`).

A naive implementation for removing that knowledge is to get the table name from the model:

```
User.joins(:ocr).select(:email, "`#{Ocr.table_name}`.`small_value_only`")
```

The next alternative relies on [merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) to get rid of the string for selecting the column:

```
 User.joins(:ocr).merge(Ocr.select(:project_id)).select(:id)
```

But as the resulting sql does not reference the Ocr table for `small_value_only`, it would be equivalent to writing:

```
 User.joins(:ocr).select(:email, :small_value_only)
```

and will only work as long as `small_value_only` does not also exist on the `users` table.

The last alternative does not have that shortcoming but is way more verbose:

```
User.joins(:ocr).select(Ocr.select(:small_value_only).arel.projections).select(:id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new association in User like:

```
belongs_to :ocr_small_value_only, -> {select('ocr.id,ocr.small_value_only')}, class_name: 'ocr', foreign_key: 'ocr_id'
```

and then query using

```
User.select('ocr_id, email').includes(:ocr_small_value_only)
```